# Why can't I connect to Google sites?

Tags: networking, dns

I'm on Windows 8.1 and I'm having a strange problem with my home network (I'm connected via ethernet to an Sitecom ADSL+ router).

Since yesterday morning, it's very difficult to reach every Google website (Google Search, Google News, YouTube, Blogspot, ...), while I can browse every other website, from Facebook to the most hidden website of the net (well, not literally).

If I try to open Google.com, most of the times (like 9 over 10) the browser stays on the "waiting for google.com" status.

## Browsers

- Tested on IE11, Firefox, Chrome. Same results.
- Tried to wipe all the caches, cookies and so on
- Tried to reset all the browser's settings to default

## Network

- **`ping google.com` returns "good" results! (ping works with latency around 60ms)**
- Tried to change the DNS, from the default given by my ISP to Google's and also OpenDNS. Nothing changes.
- Tried to flush the DNS cache with `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Tried to reboot the router (but I have not reset the configuration yet)
- I'm on IPv6 (10/10 on test-ipv6.com)

## PC and other devices

- All the PCs in this network have the same issue
- Instead, my mobile phone (that uses a totally different network) can browser Google and every other website without problems (so...well... Google works!).

What could be the cause? Could it be an ISP fault?

EDIT: This is a `tracert google.com` test:

```
C:\Users\Alessandro>tracert google.com

Traccia instradamento verso google.com [2a00:1450:4002:803::1003]
su un massimo di 30 punti di passaggio:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  2a01:2000:2001:fb07:66d1:a3ff:fe07:de81
  2     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  3    58 ms    60 ms    60 ms  2a01:20f0:2005::4
  4     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  5     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  6     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  7    63 ms    70 ms    71 ms  ibs-resid.milano30.mil.seabone.net [2001:41a8:20
:2::5]
  8     *        *        *     Richiesta scaduta.
  9    77 ms    78 ms    78 ms  2001:4860:1:1:0:1a6a:0:18
 10    66 ms    63 ms    64 ms  2001:4860::1:0:458d
 11    64 ms    63 ms    63 ms  2001:4860:0:1::207
 12    66 ms    63 ms    62 ms  mil02s05-in-x03.1e100.net [2a00:1450:4002:803::1
003]

Traccia completata.
```

Comment: did you try traceroute - check if something's gone weird with the routing? Make sure the route looks 'sensible' or someone nuked a line under the atlantic & everything's going via Azerbaijan [exaggerating]... or switch to IPv4

Comment: I don't know how to read it in the right way, but there's a lot of lines saying "Request timed out", and this happens also for non-Google websites

Comment: Don't worry about the mid-points, they can hide their details, just so long as you can trace the general route taken. Usually [but not always] you can get a general idea of which countries the route is taking. Having said that I just tried a traceroute to Google myself & got no clear idea, only IP addresses, no names. I have no issues reaching the site though, UK.

Comment: I've added the output to the question. Doesn't seem to be a "strange" routing. Anyway I'll try to switch to IPv4 in minutes

Comment: it's never leaving Milan, by the looks of that... try trace IPv4 64.233.166.100 which is Google US, just one generic address I found [I can't do IPv6, btw, my ISP isn't ready yet & I haven't needed a 6to4 setup yet]

Comment: mil02s05-in-x03.1e100.net is owned by google ...

Comment: Have you contacted your ISP?

Comment: Not yet. Anyway, I've disabled IPv6 and now everything WORKS! So, is it confirmed to be an ISP fault? (I'll call them tomorrow)